# Parsing data via API with Python. Bearer tokens

Tags: python, api, parsing, bearer-token

I’m trying to build a project, where prog automatically parses data file from API, perform calculations and returns me some output. And I find myself stuck with parsing data from API. So, the website, which I’m trying to access, says next:

```
    **Authentication and API Token
    USDA ESMIS provides the api-token to all users. Once you have created and confirmed your account, you can request the api-token by making a POST request to /user-token.

    A curl request to get the api-token:
    curl -X POST "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token" -d '{"auth": {"email":"john.smith@example.com","password":"password"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    
Authorization and API Requests
    To access the API, all requests need an api-token to be passed in the Authorization request header as a bearer token.
    
Authorization: Bearer api-token
    You can also get the api-token below using the POST request to /user_token. Use the api-token with the Authorize feature on this page to test the API.**
```

The [link to the full text](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/apidoc/index.html#/account/getUserToken).

I’m transforming the curl request into:

```
import requests

headers = {
 'accept': '*/*',
 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data:',
}

data = '{auth[email]:aaaa,auth[password]:aaaaaa}'

response = requests.post('https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token', headers=headers, data=data)
```

But getting only 400 error. As far as I understand the problem is in Bearer tokens. I’ve tried to find some FAQ’s or tutorials on this topic but without luck. Can you, please, advise in general what I need to know to parse data via API with Python with such tokens and recommend some resources to learn about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the USDA page is a little confusing. At least, the form from which you extracted `data = '{auth[email]:aaaa,auth[password]:aaaaaa}'` does not correspond to any Curl or python.requests option I know about. Not that I know about most of those options, so I could be wrong, but it didn't work for me either. What does work perfectly is the model shown in the code sample you quote:

> ```
>    A curl request to get the api-token:
>    curl -X POST "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token" -d '{"auth": {"email":"john.smith@example.com","password":"password"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
> ```

which corresponds with the Python fragment:

```
token = requests.post("https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token",
                      json={'auth':
                               {'email': 'john.smith@example.com',
                                'password':'password'}})
```

That will produce a JSON response, which you can get out of the response object's `json` method:

```
bearer = token.json()['jwt']
```

`bearer` will be a string like `'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjg2MDN9.CWZPPpzCGj8qnOrHow8eJmDkzn5sSpSoFPffgq57Ayo'`, which is what you need to supply to your API requests.

The easiest way to do that seems to me to just supply the header directly. (Undoubtedly, `requests` provides an mechanism for doing this, so if you scour the docs you might find it. I didn't do that because doing it by hand is so easy.)

```
data = requests.get(
    'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/publication/search?q=Avocado',
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token.json()['jwt']})
```

Again, it will be easiest to use the `json` method to extract the information:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(data.json())
[{'agency': ['National Agricultural Statistics Service'],
  'agency_acronym': ['NASS'],
  'contact_email': ['nass@nass.usda.gov'],
  'contact_organization': ['National Agricultural Statistics Service'],
  'description': ['This special publication reports on the damage done to the '
                  'citrus, avocado, vegetable, and sugar cane crops in Florida '
                  'following Hurricane Cleo in 1964. '],
  'frequency': ['Seasonal'],
  'id': 'dv13zt23r',
  'identifier': ['SpecHurrDa'],
  'keywords': ['Citrus',
               'hurricanes',
               'weather',
               'sugarcane',
               'avocados',
               'vegetables'],
  'resource_type': ['Report'],
  'status': ['Inactive'],
  'subject': ['Crops and Crop Products:Sugar Crops',
              'Crops and Crop Products:Fruits',
              'Agriculture Economics and Management:Weather',
              'Crops and Crop Products:Vegetables and Pulses'],
  'subscribable': 'No',
  'title': ['Special Hurricane Damage Report: August 26-27, 1964']},
   
   ...
```